# TextWatcher and SharedPreferences don't recognize Edittext after first value is entered

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, textwatcher

I am encountering a problem in my Android application.  The problem is that the `Edittext` is not being changed with a `TextWatcher` and a `SharedPreferences`.  IT WORKS FINE WITHOUT A SHAREDPREFERENCES.  Here's my code:

```
public interface CurrencyConverter {
    public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo)
            throws Exception;
}

public class YahooCurrencyConverter implements CurrencyConverter {
    public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo)
            throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom
                        + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return Double.parseDouble(responseBody);
    }
}
public String convertvalues(String convertfrom, String convertto) {
    double current;
    double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText()
            .toString());
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
    try {
        current = ycc.convert(convertfrom, convertto);
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val * current));
        return "passed";
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return "passed";
    }
}

private void addListenerOnButton2() {
    edittextdollars.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }
         
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
               
           }
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {
                String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
           //TextView myOutputBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myOutputBox);
           //myOutputBox.setText(s);
                String hello = edittextdollars.getText().toString();
                if (hello.matches("")) {
                    img1.setImageDrawable(null);
                    edittexteuros.setText("");
                }
                if (edittextdollars.getText().toString().length() != 0) {                          
                if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR")) {
                    try {
                       convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
                       getGraph("USD", "EUR");
                       String hello1 = edittextdollars.getText().toString();
                        double hello2 = Double.parseDouble(hello1);
                        String hello3 = edittexteuros.getText().toString();
                        double hello4 = Double.parseDouble(hello3);
                        String h = Double.toString(hello4 / hello2);
                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("rohit", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.data1), h);
                        editor.commit();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("rohit", 0);
                        String name2 = sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.data1), "not found");
                        double name3 = Double.parseDouble(name2);
                        String hello1 = edittextdollars.getText().toString();
                        double hello2 = Double.parseDouble(hello1);
                        double ee = hello2 * name3;
                        //String h = Double.toString(ee);
                        //edittexteuros.setText(h);
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
                        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(hello2 * name3));
                    }
               }
```

It works here:

[image: Works fine here]

But it doesn't here:

[image: Doesn't work here]

By the way, `edittextdollars` is the top edittext, `edittexteuros` is the bottom edittext, `spinner1` is the top spinner, and `spinner2` is the bottom spinner.

What is wrong here?  What problem have I encountered?  The reason I use sharedpreferences is when the internet connection is down.  As I said, it works flawlessly with internet connection.  So what did I add in the SharedPreferences that was wrong?

Any help would be appreciated regarding this problem.

Comment: The problem is not clear, what exactly do you need?

Comment: @vgarzom The problem is as I type in a value for an edittext, it works (sort of).  It works when I put the first value, but when I put the second value in, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I edited my question so you can better understand it.

Comment: Where do you call the method addListenerOnButton2() ? BestRegards

Comment: @vgarzom It's in the code, like the third or fourth method.

Comment: It's in the code, like the third or fourth method.

Comment: Actually is stranger. Do you change the edittexteuros' text somewhere else using the information in sharedpreferences? because you use convertvalues for setting the text but save the value after calling the method, the problem here is, if the server does not send the answer immediately what you save is the old value (not the new). I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I think this behavior is what you expect.